# Updating a node's position while adding new ones?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a enemy node that moves by updating its position in the update method, I add new nodes in a set interval, when two of the same nodes appear, the most recent one updates its position and the last node doesn't update its position, how do I write my code accordingly to update all the positioning of my enemy nodes when I add more?

**The Enemy Method**

```
-(void)Enemies {

SKTexture *pM1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"enemy-1"];

enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:pM1];
enemy.zPosition = 8;
enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:enemy.size];
enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = fEnemyCategory;
enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = fPlatformCategory | fMainPlatformCategory | fPlayerCategory | fPitOfCertainDoomCategory;
enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = fPlatformCategory | fPlayerCategory | fEnemyCategory;
enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
enemy.physicsBody.friction = 0.3;
enemy.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.7;
enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
enemy.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
enemy.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 30, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
enemy.position = CGPointMake(730, enemy.position.y - 129);
NSLog(@"Spawned");

[self addChild:enemy];
[enemy runAction:runAnimation];
}
```

**Update Method**

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

if (gameStart == YES & gameOver == NO) {

if (enemyExists == YES) {

        if (switchMovement == NO) {
            enemy.position = CGPointMake(enemy.position.x - 3.66, enemy.position.y);
        }
        else if (switchMovement == YES) {
            enemy.position = CGPointMake(enemy.position.x + 2.83, enemy.position.y);
        }

}
```

Comment: you need to use an NSMutableArray, right now you have a single ivar named enemy that holds a reference to exactly one enemy

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Might I ask how to implement it a NSMutableArray?  Because this particular enemy will spawn over and over, the same exact one and I'm not all that familiar with NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would implement what @LearnCocos2D has mentioned.  I make no promises on casting the object as a spritenode properly ;)

Define Array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Add Enemy to Array:

```
[array addObject:myObject];  //Directly after [self addChild:enemy];
```

New Update:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

     if (gameStart == YES & gameOver == NO) 
     {    
           for (NSObject* o in array1)
            {
                 SKSpriteNode enemyTemp = (SKSpriteNode*)o;

                 if (switchMovement == NO) 
                 {
                        enemyTemp.position = CGPointMake(enemyTemp.position.x - 3.66, enemy.position.y);
                  }
                  else if (switchMovement == YES) 
                  {
                        enemyTemp.position = CGPointMake(enemyTemp.position.x + 2.83, enemy.position.y);
                  }
              }
         }
```

Comment: In order to avoid the Exists check, remove the enemy from the array if it is removed from the scene.  This guarantees that each array object exists and will help with your efficiency.  Otherwise, your array could end up holding thousands of enemies (takes more time to traverse through the array) when only 15 or so enemies should be moved.